# System Call Tutorial - Hello World

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I'm having trouble getting my kernel messages to update. I think I may have corrupted my kernel since the KERN ALERT messages do not seem to be updating.

I called "dmesg" command and this is what was displayed:

```
Jan 20 18:18:59 cu-cs-vm kernel: [29194.126766] hello world
```

But after updating the helloworld.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>

asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void)
{
 printk(KERN_ALERT "Why isn't this working now???");
 return 0;
}
```

It still prints:
Jan 20 18:35:25 cu-cs-vm kernel: [30178.146268] hello world

This is my script for testing it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int id;
    id = syscall(318);
    printf("should print out zero: %d\n", id);
    return 0;
}
```

printf does print 0 and not -1, which is good, but why isn't the kernel message updating from "hello world" to "Why isn't this working now???" I have recompiled. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it if you can share it with me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you reloaded the module using modprobe?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with modprobe, but my problem is that I don't know which module is causing the trouble. Not sure which one to reload.

Comment: Make sure you have unloaded the previously loaded module using `rmmod` and then insert the recently compiled module using `insmod`

Comment: How exactly did you compile *and install* your `helloworld.c`?

Comment: `modprobe` (as `insmod/rmod` in case you provide the path to the .ko file) is a **must** when developing kernel modules. You write a module, compile it, and the register it using `modprobe/insmod`, when reloading, `modprobe -r` (or rmmode) must be called.

Answer (score 0):

You had it working, so your code isn't the problem, the problem is either your kernal installation or your versioning.   `insmod` wont overwrite it if the version isn't newer.   Fully remove the old install (`rmmod`) before installing the new one (`insmod`) or bump the version.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/rmmod

http://linux.die.net/man/8/insmod

Even the man pages suggest using `modprobe` instead.   Maybe you should give it a try, its pretty easy.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe

Of course with `modprobe` you can simply give it a `--force` to ignore a lot of the version checking.  But, what you need is the `-v` option so you can look at the errors about why the module is rejected.

The system may also need a reboot if the kernel is already loaded/cached.